# Query for simple condition of my sql

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I Want to write a simple query. that check whole column, if column contains one values after point for example(5.1,2.6,3.7,0.3 etc) then it just plus 0.01 in that value

Comment: if a time column has value like 4.2, it means that 4 mints and 20 sec , so some people think that oh this means 4 mints and 2 secs. to overcome this confusion i want add one sec in that field, and updated field will be 4.21.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the way you read the field to this:

```
select convert(varchar,CONVERT(decimal(10,2),123.1))
```

if the field is a string field, you may update it:

```
update table set value = convert(varchar,CONVERT(decimal(10,2),value))
```

if the field is decimal, you cannot store zeros behind that and have to add that trailing 1.

```
update table set value = CONVERT(decimal(10,1),value) + 0.01
where value == ROUND(value,1)
```

Watch the where statement, so the query will only update the rows that have just one decimal.

Comment: the value field has datatype double

Comment: So try the 3rd code sample or read the value to php with the first select.

Comment: thanks for your answers, i solved this problem thanks, now i have a simple  an other problem . i want to sort result column and then  update the position column . for example if A has least result value then Position column become 1. and it check how has 2nd least value and then it update postion column by 2. and so on .

Comment: try to add `order by mycolumn asc` or `order by mycolumn desc`. Plz mark the answer that lead to your solution, so your question is visible to be solved. If you solved it otherways, pls post your solution as answer and mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try the following idea:

```
select my_value + ((ceil(my_value * 10) = (my_value * 10)) / 100)
from my_table
```

`my_table` is the table you have your value in. `my_value` is the value you try to query. `my_value * 10` is integer if and only if the value has a single digit after the `.`. `ceil(my_value * 10) = (my_value * 10)` is 1 if the number is integer, otherwise it is 0. So we get a 1 when we need to add 0.01 and a 0 when we need to leave it as it is. So, if we divide the result with 100 and add it to `my_value`, we will get the desired output.